# Compute the higher derivatives of $B(h,h)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

I'm trying compute the higher derivatives of $B(h,h)$, but I'm stuck when I tried compute the second derivative of this question. I would like to know if my attempt is correct and how can I found the second derivative of $B(h,h)$

> $\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ defined by $f(x) := B(x,x)$, where $B: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a bilinear form. Compute the higher derivatives of $f$.
>
> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> I know that $B$ is differentiable and $DB(a,b) \cdot (h,k) = B(a,k) + B(h,b)$ for every $(a,b), (h,k) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Defining $C: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ by $C(h) := (h,h)$ e noting that $C$ is linear, I know that $DC(h) \cdot k = C(k)$ for every $h, k \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> By the Chain of Rule,
>
> $Df(x) \cdot h = D \left( B \circ C \right)(x) = DB(C(x)) \circ DC(x) \cdot h = DB((x,x)) \ \circ \ C(h)$
>
> $ = DB((x,x)) \cdot (h,h) = B(x,h) + B(h,x) = 2 B(x,h)$

for every $h, k \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

> Using the definition of differentiability to compute $D^2f(h)$, I found
>
> $Df(x+h) \cdot h = Df(x) \cdot h + D^2f(x) \cdot (h,h) + r(h)$
>
> $2 B(x+h,h) = 2 B(x,h) + D^2f(x) \cdot (h,h) + r(h)$
>
> $2 B(x,h) + 2 B(h,h) = 2 B(x,h) + D^2f(x) \cdot (h,h) + r(h)$
>
> $2 B(h,h) = D^2f(x) \cdot (h,h) + r(h)$
>
> By the continuity of $B$ and $D^2f(x)$, I have that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} r(h) = 0$, which implies that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{r(h)}{||h||} = 0$, then $Df(x)$ is differentiable, but this don't give me the second derivative of $f$.

How can I found the second derivative of $f$? Is it easy find the $n$-th order derivative of $f$ for $n \geq 3$ once I have the second derivative of $f$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first have a comment: based on what you wrote, you're not only supposing that $B$ is bilinear, but also **symmetric**.

Now, you correctly proved that $Df(x).h = 2 B(x,h)$. Which implies that $Df$ is a linear application defined from $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$.

You also know (or you can prove) that the derivative of a linear map $L$ is the constant linear map $L$. Therefore $f$ second derivative is constant and equal to $2B$. As the derivative of a constant map is zero, the higher than $2$ derivatives of $f$ are all equal to zero.

Comment: I thought that second derivative of $f$ is a constant linear map because $Df(x)$ is a linear map, but I found difficult to argue this. How can I argue this? Is it $D^2f(x) \cdot (h,h) = 2B(x,h)$?

Comment: You have $Df(x+k).h=2B(x+k,h)=2B(x,h)+2B(k,h)=Df(x).h+2B(k,h)$. Hence $D^2f(x).(h,h) = 2B(h,h)$ which is indeed independent from $x$.

Comment: I understood, thanks a lot!